# Set the browser to be used to open URLs in iOS App Webview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, webview, uiwebview

I am developing an app for my company and our idea is to use a webview to load embedded content from a BI tool.

Does any of you know how to set which browser the app should use as a loader for the webview? The app will run on company phones with a company profile installed and Mobile Iron/Web@Work as secure browser.

By defining Web@Work as the browser where the app will load the webviews, users will be able to securely authenticate within our network.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Content loaded inside a UIWebView is always rendered by Safari.
There isn't a way to modify it in order to use another browser.

If Web@Work has an API for developers, you could load the data using it.